# Switching windows and focus in WebDriver with non-angular pages

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have two non-angular pages, one has a form which I have been able to input text and once I click the Invoke button I get another browser window (shown as a  tab in Chrome) with some text output. The new tab becomes the focus for a bit, but once I try to get a new element it focuses back on the first tab. Here's what my test look like:

```
beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('Do authentication of session', function () {
        session.goToCommandPage().then(function () {
            browser.findElement(by.css('#content > span:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a', 'AuthenticateUser')).click();
        }).then(function () {
            browser.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input')).sendKeys(COMPANY_ID);
        }).then(function () {
            browser.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input')).sendKeys('ADMIN');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.findElement(by.buttonText('Invoke')).click();
        }).then(function () {
            browser.sleep(7000);
        })
    });

    it('Switch to the results tab', function () {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                console.log('Title: ' + title);
            });
            if (handles.length === 2) {
                browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
                    browser.sleep(7000);
                }).then(function () {
                    browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                        console.log('Title now: ' + title);
                    });
                    browser.findElement(by.css('.collapsible .expanded .text')).getText().then(function (textProduced) {
                        console.log('Text printed: ' + textProduced);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

As you can see above I try to use handles, but where I access the handles[1] it doesn't visually change the tabs to the second one. This code just hangs where I get the handles. I see the title printed and it is that of the first form, but it just times out after that giving me a ScriptTimeoutError. I even tried to send keys to the body and that did change the tabs but the elements of the second tab couldn't be found. I am using Chrome and Protractor to run my test. I normally work with angular pages, but these two are not angular pages, but are doing things that I will later check in a angular page.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have edited my code to go through the handles and changing based on the title of the page. It doesn't seem to change to another tab. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong? NOTE: This is written in JavaScript.

```
it('Switch to the results tab', function () {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                console.log('Title: ' + title);
            });
            if (handles.length > 1) {
                handles.forEach(function (tab) {
                    browser.switchTo().window(tab).then(function () {
                        browser.sleep(7000);
                    }).then(function () {
                        browser.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                            console.log('Title now: ' + title);
                            if(title != 'WebService Web Service') {
                                browser.findElement(by.css('.collapsible .expanded .text')).getText().then(function (textProduced) {
                                    console.log('Text printed: ' + textProduced);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: browser window/tab. How would I refer to a tab by title. The first tab has a formal html title element, but the next one just has the url in the title area of the tab (in chrome) i.e. localhost/Service/...

Comment: How do you refer to a tab by its title? I have been looking online for an example, but so far all I have found is how to get the title of the browser window, as I did above.

Comment: It's a window, not a tab. The title of the browser window _is_ the title of the browser "tab". A tab is a visual effect provided by Firefox, Chrome etc. Selenium just cares about HTML pages, and it uses the word "window" to describe a container of pages. To refer to a "tab" by its title, use `driver.getTitle()` after you switch to the window. To robustly switch to a new window ("tab"), you should get all window handles before opening the window, then get all window handles afterwards, then switch to the handle that is in the "after" list and not in the "before" list.

Comment: I attempted going through the handles and switching based on Title. Still didn't seem to work. (see Edit above).

Comment: That looks better (caveat: I've never used JS webdriver). Are your `console.logs` looking like the right things are happening? If you change from repeated `browser.sleep(7000)` to an initial `browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(7000);` does it get any better?

Comment: I replaced browser.sleep(7000) to browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(7000); and that just gave me the error I was getting before, but sooner: "ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000"

Perhaps I should stop using JS webdriver and use Java instead. :/

Comment: Ah, I should have asked what the error was sooner. That looks like your test harness is timing out, because Selenium is waiting for your app to serve some pages, and the pages are either not being served, or are not finishing loading soon enough. It may be something as simple as you're calling `getAllWindowHandles()` too soon, before the second window / tab has opened. Debugging will help.

Comment: I will look into this. More soon, well tomorrow. Thank you so much!!

Comment: So this works when I ran it the first time, see updated code below, but subsequent runs fail. I tried increasing my sleep and the pageLoadTimeout value, but that doesn't fix it consistently. Do you have any idea why it would still throw a "ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from render: 10.000"

Comment: I'd suggest creating a helper to wrap your calls that will use [`ExpectedConditions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) instead of explicit `browser.sleep` statements. Also, can you provide a single, smaller, spec that reproduces it? It's much easier to focus on finding a solution that way.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried that, but it still hangs when accessing the getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) { browser.switchTo().window(handle[1]). Is there a way to wait to make sure I'm not trying to access the new opened window using ExpectedConditions? I kept getting errors when I tried to do it because I  kept getting "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined", which I attributed to it being that my pages aren't angular.

Comment: @NickTomlin See Answer 1 for the code I used to switch to the new generated window.If I use handle[0] it just tells me it can't find the element on that page. If I use handle[1] I get a "ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer", my guess is that I am not waiting for that window to be ready before I switch to it, but I don't know how to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Code I use to transfer to the newly opened window, but it results in a "ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer".

```
it('Switch to the results tab', function () {
        browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                console.log('Title: ' + title);
            });
            if (handles.length > 1) {
                browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function () {
                    browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(7000);
                }).then(function () {
                    var outputElement = $('.collapsible .expanded .collapsible-content .text');
                    var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(outputElement);
                    browser.wait(isClickable, 12000, 'Waiting for output element');
                }).then(function () {
                    browser.driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                        console.log('Title now: ' + title);
                        browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.collapsible .expanded .collapsible-content .text')).getText().then(function (textProduced) {
                            console.log('Text printed: ' + textProduced);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

---

The code below runs sometimes, but most of the time it fails.

Here is the code modified:

```
describe('Test', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('Do authentication of session', function () {
        session.goToCommandPage().then(function () {
            browser.sleep(12000);
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.click();
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the AuthenticateUser link to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.sendKeys(COMPANY_ID);
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the Company ID field to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.sendKeys('ADMIN');
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the User field to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.submit();
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the Invoke button to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.sleep(7000);
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

                    if (handles.length > 1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for window count to be greater than 1');
        });
    });

    it('Switch to the results tab', function () {
        browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            browser.driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                console.log('Title: ' + title);
            });
            if (handles.length > 1) {
                handles.forEach(function (tab) {
                    browser.driver.switchTo().window(tab).then(function () {
                        browser.sleep(7000);
                    }).then(function () {
                        browser.driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                            console.log('Title now: ' + title);
                            if(title == 'localhost/Service/WebService.asmx/AuthenticateUser') {
                                browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.collapsible .expanded .collapsible-content .text')).getText().then(function (textProduced) {
                                    console.log('Text printed: ' + textProduced);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am not sure why I can't get this to pass consistently.